# Is there any alternative for PHP exec(), shell_exec(), system(), passthrough() functions?

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

Is there any alternative for PHP exec(), shell_exec(), system(), passthrough() functions? As all these functions have security risk, need a way to execute server commands without using any of these functions.

Due to security reasons, can't enable these functions on my server php configuration. But as per website requirement, I need to execute some external commands like server ssh commands through php script. So, if there are any alternative ways to achieve same then please reply back to me.

Comment: You can write shell or bash scripts and invoke them through cron or set a daemon and let it check for a specific flag in database.

Answer (score 1):

You can write shell or bash scripts and invoke them through cron or set a daemon and let it check for a specific flag in database if you can do that.

Comment: My basic requirement is to transfer data files from Server A to Server B. And this data transfer is not always, it will invoke only if user clicks on button. So I don't think cron/daemon is the solution for it.