# exec() disabled, how to execute .jar file

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

PHP's `exec()` function is turned off in my hosting server and it's not possible to change it (for security reasons). Are there alternatives for the `exec()` function?

Here is more info about my problem:

What I want to do: *I want to use .jar file in host server*.

This is how it looks on my `localhost`:

```
function generateReqXML() {
   exec('"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\java.exe"
                 -jar vaiisis.jar auth', $out);
 }
```

This `.jar` file help my system to generate XML code.

This code work perfect for my local machine, but its facing the problem when I am trying to use it in my host server.

Comment: As it should be, what are you trying to do?

Comment: If the hosting server does not want you to use any exec-like functionality then doing so via workarounds would be very "naughty" of you. However there may be a build-in PHP function that does what you need, so you can tell us that that is.

Comment: Specify what you are trying to do and how you have attempted to solve it. We can help from there.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25281280/924299) helpful; it suggests a workflow of `PHP > Python > Java`. Another idea [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224251/is-there-any-alternative-for-php-exec-shell-exec-system-passthrough-f) is to execute via a bash script run by cron based on a database value set by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to exec are:

```
system(); passthru(); shell_exec();
```

You can check if these are available with `echo ini_get("disable_functions");`

But since these are probably disabled there are only non-PHP options left.

Do you have to use the exec() function via PHP? 
You could for example write a shell script, which can be invoked via cron to do your job.

What are you exactly trying to accomplish?

Comment: I answer about what exactly i want to accomplish - above few answers.